# Display dataframe as a handle on Excel via XLwings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlwings, pyxll

I am trying to write a function to return dataframe by handle via `Xlwings`:

```
@xw.func
@xw.ret(index=False)
def create_df():
    # initialize data of lists. 
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]} 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

    return df
```

When applied on excel, it will automatically display the whole dataframe. In `PyXLL` the way of returning dataframe is by handle (for the same function). May I ask if there is a way to do the same in python `Xlwings`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question corretly. If you would like to insert the dataframe to a single cell of an excel worksheet you can orientate yourself on the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
                   'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
                  )

wb = xw.Book(r"test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws["A5"].value = df.to_string()  # "A5" specifies the address of the excel cell.
```

Comment: I would like to call the create_df function on excel via xlwings, instead of displaying the whole dataframe fully, I would like the df to be show up as an object occupying one cell only.

Comment: Use `df.to_string()`.